# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class java.UserScoresServlet

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I've been researching similar topics to this, but none of the solutions have worked. I'm trying to map a simple HttpServlet in a Web Application using Eclipse, but have been getting the following error when the form is submitted from the html page that calls get on the servlet.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class java.UserScoresServlet

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class java.UserScoresServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class java.UserScoresServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.UserScoresServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.
```

I've tried mapping both with the @WebServlet annotation as well as the Web.xml file to no avail. I was trying to use one or the other, not both at the same time. When using JSP's and HTML pages my mapping works correctly. My XML file mapping is as follows, and is located in the WEB-INF directory.

```
<display-name>GetUserScores</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetUserScores</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>java.UserScoresServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetUserScores</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetUserScores</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The server class is as follows. As I mentioned above, I've been doing either the annotation, or the web.xml, not both. Both throw the same exception.

```
package java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.score.jpa.Score;
import java.score.jpa.ScoreService;
import java.user.jpa.User;
import java.user.jpa.UserService;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class UserScoresServlet
 */
@WebServlet(name = "GetUserScores", urlPatterns = "/GetUserScores")
public class UserScoresServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserService userService;
    private ScoreService scoreService;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UserScoresServlet() {
    super();
    userService = new UserService();
    scoreService = new ScoreService();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstName = (String)request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = (String)request.getParameter("firstName");
    User user = userService.findUserByFirstAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
    if (user != null){
        List<Score> scoreList = scoreService.findAllScoresByUser(user);
        request.setAttribute("scoreList", scoreList);
    }
    gotoPage("/scores", request, response);
}

private void gotoPage(String address, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

See photo for the file structure: [File Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWJJt.png)

Any help anyone could provide would be a big help. I've searched this site thoroughly and tried every suggestion of similar issues to no avail. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace as formatted text within your question, not as image.

Comment: Corrected. Forgive the first post, Hopefully I formatted correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2), you should not use `java` as name for your development packages:

> Names of packages intended only for local use should have a first identifier that begins with a lowercase letter, but that first identifier specifically should not be the identifier `java`; package names that start with the identifier `java` are reserved for package of the Java SE platform

Noted here in your code:

```
package java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.score.jpa.Score;
import java.score.jpa.ScoreService;
import java.user.jpa.User;
import java.user.jpa.UserService;
import java.util.List;

//rest of code...
```

Change the name of your package to something else.